# MIPS array in order

Tags: mips

I just received some help with a problem I had with some MIPS code in this question (Trouble with MIPS array) and the code they gave me works fine. Now I'm trying to add a sorting algorithm to sort the integers stored in the array, but the output I get is just a 0 followed by the string I put as input (the correct output should be the date followed by the string). That's the code I'm working on:

```
.data
num_array:   .space 400 #array
str_array:   .space 400
in_name: .asciiz "\nInsert name: "
in_date: .asciiz "\nInsert date (mmdd): "
appt:    .asciiz "\nList: "
spaz:    .asciiz " "
.text
main:      
la $s0, num_array        #load array in s0
la $s1, str_array
addi $t0, $zero, 0       #t0=0 counter
addi $s2, $zero, 0       #s1=0 array size counter
j    Input

Input:
# prompt for date
li  $v0, 4           
la  $a0, in_date
syscall

# read date
li  $v0, 5          
syscall

# store date in the num_array
sw $v0, 0($s0)

# increment counter and move to next position in the array
addi $t0, $t0, 1
addi $s2, $s2, 1
addi $s0, $s0, 4

# prompt for name
li      $v0, 4
la      $a0, in_name          
syscall                         #ask name

# store name (max 4 bytes) to str_array ($s1)  
move $a0, $s1
li      $a1, 4
li      $v0, 8
syscall                         #read name

# move to the beginnig of next string in $s1
# increment by 4 because length of each input word is 4
addi $s1, $s1, 4

beq $s2, 5, sort         #if array size=10 go to print
j   Input               #start over until s1=10

sort:

    addi    $t1, $zero, 0       
    addi    $t2, $zero, 0       
    addi    $s3, $zero, 0       #swap flag set at 0
    move    $t1, $s0        #first element of array in t1
    addi    $t2, $s0, 4     #second element of array in t2
        jal     ric
    j       print
ric: 
        add     $sp, $sp, -4            #stack pointer
    sw      $ra, 0($sp)             
  pro:  
    addi    $t5, $t5, 1     #counter t0++
    beq $t5, $s2, exit          #if counter=array size go to exit
    bgt $t1, $t2, swap          #swap if t1<t2
    j   pro         #go back
  swap:
    move    $t3, $t1               #$t3=$t1
            move    $t1, $t2               #$t1=$t2
            move    $t2, $t3               #$t2=$t3=$t1
    addi    $s3, $s3, 1     #s3++ (swap flag)   
    j   pro         #go back 
  exit:
    move    $s0, $t1
    addi    $s0, $s0, 4
        bgtz    $s3, sort       #if 2 elements were swapped start over
    lw      $ra, 0($sp)             #load return address
    add     $sp, $sp, 4             
    jr      $ra             #exit   

print:
# print "List:"
la  $a0, appt           
li  $v0, 4          
syscall             #print list

addi    $t0, $zero, 0       #t0=0 counter    
la $s0, num_array # address of num_array
la $s1, str_array # address of str_array
res:
# get number from num_array and print it
lw $a0, 0($s0)
li $v0, 1
syscall

# move to the next element, increment by 4 because numbers take 1 word = 4 bytes
addi $s0, $s0, 4 

# print space
la $a0, 32
li $v0, 11
syscall

# get string from str_array and print it
la $a0, 0($s1)
li $v0, 4
syscall

# print space
la $a0, 32
li $v0, 11
syscall

# move to the next element, increment by 4 because strs have 4 bytes length (in your case)
addi $s1, $s1, 4

# increment loop counter
addi $t0, $t0, 1
blt $t0, $s2, res # $s2 is size of the array


end:
li  $v0, 10         
syscall             #the end
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? Also, any suggestion on how I could have as output the sorted number followed by the corresponding string? (so the first given as input should follow the first date given as input, even after they get sorted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to sort numeric array and keep track of corresponding entries in the string array (as you shuffle around the value in numeric array do the same thing in the string array). I suggest you start implementing a simple sorting algorithm and sort numbers first. For example, consider implementing bubble sort. For this you might consider implementing swap procedure to swap 2 values.

Here is he mips version of the program. It implements bubble sort procedure. I have hardcoded numeric and string arrays at the top of the file (so you have to do some adjustments to make it work with your code). The idea is the following: when I swap numbers in the numeric array I also swap corresponding strings in the string array.

```
.data
    array: .word 3,2,1,4
    str_array: .ascii "ccc\0bbb\0aaa\0ddd\0"
    n: .word 4
.text

j main

str_swap:
    # swap two strings
    # $a0 - beginning of the first str
    # $a1 - beginning of the second str
    # Assume that str length is 3
    li $t6, 0 # loop counter
    li $t7, 3 # str length
str_loop:
    bgt $t6, $t7, str_loop_end
    lb $t8, 0($a0)  
    lb $t9, 0($a1)
    sb $t8, 0($a1)
    sb $t9, 0($a0)
    addi $a0, $a0, 1
    addi $a1, $a1, 1
    addi $t6, $t6, 1
    b str_loop
str_loop_end:
    jr $ra

swap:
    # $a0 - address of the first num
    # $a1 - address of the second num
    # $a2 - index of the first number in the array
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    lw $s0, 0($a0)
    lw $s1, 0($a1)
    sw $s0, 0($a1)
    sw $s1, 0($a0)

    la $a0, str_array
    sll $a2, $a2, 2   # $a2 = $a2 * 4
    add $a0, $a0, $a2 # address of the first str
    addi $a1, $a0, 4  # address of the next string
    jal str_swap

    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra

sort:
    # sort in non-decreasing order
    # $a0 - address of the array
    # $a1 - length of the array
    addi $sp, $sp, -12
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    sw $a0, 4($sp)
    sw $a1, 8($sp)
    li $t0, 0 # outer index 
    move $t2, $a1
    subi $t2, $t2, 1 # upper bound = length - 1
outer:
    bgt $t0, $t2, outer_end
    li $t1, 0 # inner index
    lw $a0, 4($sp)
    inner:
        bge $t1, $t2, inner_end
        lw $t3, 0($a0) # $t3 = a[i]
        lw $t4, 4($a0) # $t4 = a[i+1]
        move $t5, $a0       # save $a0 in $t5
        bgt $t3, $t4, swap_elements # if a[i] > a[i+1]
        b inner_continue
    swap_elements:
        addi $a1, $a0, 4
        move $a2, $t1
        jal swap
    inner_continue:
        addi $t1, $t1, 1    # increment inner counter
        move $a0, $t5
        addi $a0, $a0, 4    # move to the next position in the array
        b inner

    inner_end:
        addi $t0, $t0, 1    # increment outer loop
        b outer
outer_end:
    lw $ra, 0($sp)  # restore $ra
    addi $sp, $sp, 12
    jr $ra


main:
    la $a0, array
    lw $a1, n
    jal sort # bubble sort the array

    addi    $t0, $zero, 0       #t0=0 counter    
    la $s0, array # address of num_array
    la $s1, str_array # address of str_array
    lw $s2, n
res:
    # get number from num_array and print it
    lw $a0, 0($s0)
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    # move to the next element, increment by 4 because numbers take 1 word = 4 bytes
    addi $s0, $s0, 4 

    # print space
    la $a0, 32
    li $v0, 11
    syscall

    # get string from str_array and print it
    la $a0, 0($s1)
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    # print space
    la $a0, 32
    li $v0, 11
    syscall

    # move to the next element, increment by 4 because strs have 4 bytes length (in your case)
    addi $s1, $s1, 4

    # increment loop counter
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    blt $t0, $s2, res # $s2 is size of the array
end:
    li  $v0, 10         
    syscall             #the end
```

So given this input:

```
array: .word 3,2,1,4
str_array: .ascii "ccc\0bbb\0aaa\0ddd\0"
n: .word 4
```

this gives the following output:

```
1 aaa 2 bbb 3 ccc 4 ddd 
-- program is finished running --
```